# intellij maven output link

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, prettify

How can i manage that the maven output compile errors in intellij output window are shown as links?
That would be very helpfull!

i am currently using intellij idea 10.2. My output is just a bunch of Text. i am using the scala maven plugin... perhaps thats the problem.. i dont know how the links to the files are produced.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version are you using? I am using 9.0.3 and my compilation failures are links (it opens the java file when I click it). I can't remember having to configure it anywhere.

Comment: i am currently using intellij idea 10.2. My output is just a bunch of Text. i am using the scala maven plugin... perhaps thats the problem.. i dont know how the links to the files are produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works automatically if you have sources for the files you build attached in your project.

Comment: Provide the sample of Maven output with file paths which are not recognized.